Proving that $\left|\sum_{n<x}\mu(n)\right|\ll x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x})$ for some $c>0$

Assume that for $\sigma\ge 1-\frac{1}{(\log(2+|t|)^2}$ we have $$|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\gg\frac{1}{(\log(2+|t|))^2}.$$ Using Perron's formula and moving the line of integration to $\textrm{Re}(s)=1-\frac{1}{\log T}$, prove that $$\left|\sum_{n<x}\mu(n)\right|\ll x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x})$$ for some constant $c>0$.

I am having trouble understanding the solution to this. I will give part of the solution given by my instructor and then explain where I am stuck.
Solution: By Perron's formula, for $2\le T\le 2x$ and $c=1+\frac{1}{\log x}$, $$\sum_{n<x}\mu(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{x^s}{s\zeta(s)}+O\left(\frac{x(\log x)^3}{T}\right).$$
For simplicity denote $F(s):=\frac{x^s}{s\zeta(s)}$, and let $c'=1-\frac{1}{\log T}$.  Now, $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros in $\textrm{Re}(s)\ge 1-\frac{1}{\log T}$, and $|\textrm{Im}(s)|\le T$. So by Cauchy's Residue Theorem: $$\int_{c'-iT}^{c'+iT}F(s)ds+\int_{c'+iT}^{c+iT}F(s)ds+\int_{c+iT}^{c-iT}F(s)ds+\int_{c-iT}^{c'-iT}F(s)ds=0,$$ because $F$ has no poles in this region.
Now we bound each of these integrals; in the first one, we have $|x^s|=x^{\textrm{Re}(s)}=x^{1-\frac{1}{\log T}}$ and $1/|s|\ll\frac{1}{(2+|t|)}$, and $$\frac{1}{|\zeta(s)|}\ll\log(2+|t|)^2\ll (\log T)^2.$$ Therefore $$F(s)\ll x^{1-\frac{1}{\log T}}\frac{\log^2T}{2+|t|}$$ etc., and then the solution is essentially to bound the integrals, which I kind of get.
I understand the use of Perron at the beginning to get an expression for $\sum_{n<x}\mu(n)$. It makes sense as well to introduce a simpler function, namely $F(s)$ for our purposes.

Is defining $c':=1-\frac{1}{\log T}$ 'moving the line of integration' as we want, or does it mean something else?

I strongly suspect this is what this is doing, but the approach does confuse me.

When using Cauchy's Residue Theorem, I am not sure how one would come up with this particular sum; it seems as though they are integrating over a rectangular contour but I can't see how they are doing this (i.e. how one would draw this); also, when they are bounding each of the integrals, I really cannot see how they are doing this - is there an easy way to understand this strategy?


Let's think about this from a very far perspective.
We want to estimate
$$\sum_{n \leq X} \mu(n).$$
By Perron's formula, we know we can do this by looking at the analytic behavior of the associated Dirichlet series $\zeta(s)^{-1}$, and in particular
for any $c$ in the domain of absolute convergence (i.e. $c > 1$),
$$ \int_{c - iT}^{c + iT} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \frac{X^s}{s} ds =
\sum_{n \leq X} \mu(n) + \mathrm{PerronError}(X, T, c). $$
The precise form of the error term in Perron's formula depends on which version one uses. In general, it grows in $X$ and $c$ and decreases in $T$. In practice, rough approximations often take the form
$$ \mathrm{PerronError}(X, T, c) \approx \frac{X \log^A X}{T} $$
for some $\log$ power.
Rearranging, we have
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \mu(n) = \int_{c - iT}^{c + iT} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \frac{X^s}{s} ds - \mathrm{PerronError}(X, T, c), $$
where $c$ is somewhere in the domain of absolute convergence.
What estimate for the sum do we get from this and no extra work? As $c > 1$, we know $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \ll 1$ on the line $\mathrm{Re}(s) = c$. So the integral is bounded by
$$ X^c \int_{-T}^T \frac{1}{\lvert c + it \rvert} dt \ll X^c \log T. $$
Thus the initial bound we get, using no additional information, is
$$ \sum_{n \leq X} \mu(n) \ll X^c \log T + \frac{X \log^A X}{T}, $$
for some $c > 1$. This is bigger than $X^c$, which is bigger than $X$.
This is a terrible bound! It's worse than the trivial bound using $\lvert \mu(n) \rvert \leq 1$.
The reason why it's poor is that taking $c > 1$ and bounding the integral naively will always give a bound at least as large as $X^c$, which is too large. We'd like to take $c$ smaller.
This is why we want to shift the line of integration left. How far left? As far left as we can, while still being able to make sense of whatever comes out.
In practice, this means we want to choose some $c' < 1$ and look at the integral over the rectangle with vertices $c - iT, c + iT, c' + iT, c' - iT$. If we choose $c'$ and $T$ so that there are no poles of the integrand in this box, then Cauchy's theorem says that
$$ \int_{c - iT}^{c + iT} + \int_{c + iT}^{c' + iT} + \int_{c' + iT}^{c' - iT} + \int_{c' - iT}^{c - iT} = 0. $$
The first integral above is exactly the Perron integral from above. Rearranging, we have
$$ \int_{c - iT}^{c + iT} = \int_{c' + iT}^{c + iT} + \int_{c' - iT}^{c' + iT} + \int_{c - iT}^{c' - iT}.$$
(I've swapped the limits on the right to account for the minus signs). We can give each of the integrals on the right a name: in order they're the TOP, LEFT, and BOTTOM of the rectangle.
The TOP and BOTTOM integrals behave very similarly. I look only at the top here. The point is that in
$$ \int_{c' + iT}^{c + iT} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \frac{X^s}{s} ds, $$
the $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ is smallish for $c'$ large enough, and the $1/s$ term is of size $1/T$. So we should expect a bound of the shape
$$ \int_{TOP} \ll \mathrm{smallish} \cdot \frac{X^c}{T}, $$
which is more like the PerronError bound and a big improvement. The BOTTOM integral is the same.
The remaining integral is the LEFT. This is usually the problematic integral, since it's long (of length $2T$) and in the critical strip. But again, if $c'$ is large enough then $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ is smallish (in a nontrivial way to show, but which your instructor appears to have done already). The shape of the LEFT integral bound is then
$$ \int_{LEFT} \ll \mathrm{smallish} \int_{-T}^T \frac{X^{c'}}{\lvert c' + it \rvert} dt \ll \mathrm{smallish} \cdot X^{c'} \log T. $$
This looks similar to the naive bound immediately after Perron, except that there is an $X^{c'}$ instead of $X^c$. As $c' < 1 < c$, this is a very large improvement.
Actually tracking down each of the bounds I called "smallish" above and optimizing over $T$, one (presumably) arrives at the proof you went over. But the point is that you have a totally explicit rectangle to apply the residue theorem to, and the left side of the rectangle is left of the line $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 1$, while the right hand side is to the right of this line.
